# Random Multiple http Requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

We have deployed a Spring MVC web application. It has been noticed that sometimes the records pushed in the database through this web application are repeated several times. 
The records are repeated randomly 2 to 900 times. 
Therefore we enabled the access logs and found that sometimes the controller is actually getting multiple requests.

We also examined our forms but found nothing wrong in it.

We have got Ubuntu 14.04, Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on our server.

Can anybody tell me the reason behind this weird behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Probably doing business logic where you're not supposed to